# Do not understand why EmberJs is not returning the model from the route

Tags: ember.js

I am using EmberJs version 1.4 and I have the following set of templates and routes. The idea is that when the user goes to the "Widgets" route the returned model is only a collection of Widget Ids and Widget names to create the links and then when the user clicks on a link a call to a service will get all of the selected widget data to be displayed on the "Widget" template.

JavaScript code

```
window.Awesome = Ember.Application.create();

Awesome.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("awesome", {path: "/"}, function(){
        this.route('login');
    });
    this.resource("widgets", function () {
        this.resource('widget', { path: '/:widgetId' }, function () {
            this.route('general', { path: 'info' });
            this.route('configuration');
            this.route('operations');
        })
    });
});


Awesome.WidgetsRoute = Awesome.AuthenticationRoute.extend({
    model: function(){
        //TODO: Call a service to get the model.
        return { widgets: [{ widgetId: 1, widgetName: "Great Widget" }, { widgetId: 2, widgetName: "Fantastic Widget" }, { widgetId: 3, widgetName: "Brutal Widget" }] };
    }
});

Awesome.WidgetIndexRoute = Awesome.AuthenticationRoute.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        var receivedWidgetId = params.widgetId;
        return { widgetName: "Hardcoded Widget", widgetId: receivedWidgetId };
    }
});
```

Handlebars templates

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="widgets">
    <section class="span3 left-section">
        <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-justified registration-actions-menu">
            <button id="createNewWidget" class="btn btn-link">Create New Widget</button>
            <button id="joinWidgetTeam" class="btn btn-link">Join Widget Team</button>
        </div>
        <div class="registered-widgets-menu">
            <div class="btn-group-vertical">
                {{#each widget in widgets}}
                    {{#link-to 'widget' widget class="btn btn-link"}}{{widget.widgetName}}{{/link-to}}
                {{/each}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="span8">
        {{outlet}}
    </section>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="widget">
    <div id="widgetOptions">
        <!-- TODO: Change the anchors for handlebars link-to helpers. -->
        <h1>{{widgetName}}</h1> <h5>{{widgetId}}</h5>
        <ul id="widgetNavigation">
            <li><a href="#">Widget Info</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Widget Configuration</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Widget Operations</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="widgetContent">
        <!-- TODO: Design some awesome widget content. -->
        Some awesome widget content
    </div>
</script>
```

The thing I do not understand is why when I click on any of the widget links from the "Widgets" template and the "Widget" template is displayed, even though I can see that the model hook on the WidgetIndexRoute gets executed, the displayed widgetName is not the hard coded one but the one that was selected on the list which leads me to believe that even though I would call a service to get additional data, this data would not be available for the template.

The other thing I do not understand is that when I debug the code the **params.widgetId** is undefined but when I try running the url with an arbitrary value, said value is displayed on the template but the widgetName is empty.

Any help is appreciated.

Out of completeness just in case this might have anything to do with it, both routes are extending this other one to support authentication:

```
Awesome.AuthenticationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    beforeModel: function(transition){
        if(!Awesome.get('loggedUser')){
            this.redirectToLogin(transition);
        }
    },

    redirectToLogin: function(transition) {
        var loginController = this.controllerFor('awesome.login');
        loginController.set('attemptedTransition', transition);
        this.transitionTo('awesome.login');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check out [this post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/03/30/ember-1-5-0-and-ember-1-6-beta-released.html) at Ember Blog about new version of Ember (1.5):

**ROUTES INHERIT MODEL**

Ember routes and leaf resources (without nested routes) will inherit the parent route's model.

Take the following example:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('post', function(){
    this.route('edit');
  });
});

App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return {title: 'ZOMG', text: 'AWESOME'};
  }
});

App.PostEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.modelFor('post');
  }
});
```

Now in 1.5, you do not have to define the model hook for PostEditRoute as the default implementation is to use the parent routes model.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question and this is not what I need actually since on the Widgets resource I only need a list of Names and Ids to create the links and on the Widget one I will eventually get all the information of the selected widget by its id. This example's purpose is to learn and understand how Ember works before I use it in my project. I am using version 1.4